# Как собрать массив из строки Excel одной формулой?

Tags: python, excel

Как сделать массив?
Сейчас получаю его так.
Нужно одной формулой.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Получение значений из таблицы excel
wb = load_workbook(filename = '/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/данные для выгрузки.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Лист1']
surname = sheet_ranges['A1'].value
name = sheet_ranges['B1'].value
patronymic = sheet_ranges['C1'].value
date_of_birth = sheet_ranges['D1'].value
gender = sheet_ranges['E1'].value
array = [surname , name, patronymic , date_of_birth , gender]
print(array)
```

Comment: получить доступ к диапазону можно cell_range = sheet_ranges[1], а вот как записать значения в массив не используя перебор пока не могу

Answer (score 0):

Решил перебором всех значений на листе:

```
array = []
for row in sheet_ranges.values:
   for value in row:
     array.append(value)
print(array)
```

Если кто знает как выбрать конкретный диапазон, напишите пожалуйста!

Comment: Пробовали [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: Нет, с ним проще?

Comment: Кардинально проще